# Converting to EPSG code gives error

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

My underlying EPSG is 4326.

When I try the following code:

```
ST_ClusterDBSCAN(st_transform(points_geom,9234)
```

I receive an error:

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Cannot find SRID (9234) in spatial_ref_sys
```

However I can run the following code without any error:

```
ST_ClusterDBSCAN(st_transform(points_geom,24313)
```

Here is the EPSG information for reference purposes:
https://epsg.io/24313-1247

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PostGIS does not know EPSG 9234.

You can check this with:

```
select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid = 9234;
```

But EPSG.io provides handy code snippets to add it https://epsg.io/9234

Just run:

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 9234, 'EPSG', 9234, '+proj=pipeline +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +inv +proj=longlat +a=6377301.243 +rf=300.8017255 +step +proj=push +v_3 +step +proj=cart +a=6377301.243 +rf=300.8017255 +step +proj=helmert +x=230.25 +y=632.76 +z=161.03 +rx=-1.114 +ry=1.115 +rz=1.212 +s=12.584 +convention=coordinate_frame +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=pop +v_3 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1', 'None');
```